# How to create calculated fields for sum of sale of current year and for previous year in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

How to create calculated fields for sum of sale of current year and for previous   year in tableau?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if statement to effectively embed your filter criteria in a calculation, evaluating to null by default for data rows that don’t satisfy your condition. Aggregation functions like Sum() silently ignore null values.

**current_year_sales**

```
If Year([Sale Date]) = Year(Today()) then [Sale Amount] end
```

**prior_year_sales**

```
If Year([Sale Date]) = Year(DateAdd(‘year’, -1, [Sale Date])) then [Sale Amount] end
```